# Selenium with chromedriver gives different results based on "headless" argument

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have been playing around with Selenium + Chromedriver and I noticed I get different results based on if headless is enabled or disabled. After some investigation I found out that "headless" does not include the `Accept-Language` header.

Is there anyway to manually add this in the headers?

Comment: See if this helps? https://gist.github.com/c089/a5cbb834f9b54004de9b

Comment: right now I am setting the header like this, but it's not adding the header

`   chromeOptions.put("args", Arrays.asList("headless", "window-size=1200x600",
     "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36",
     "--lang=en-US,en;q=0.8"));`

Comment: Open a bug with chromedriver then

Comment: Can you share with us the concerned URL?

Comment: @DebanjanB so there is another report here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/677 and the website I was having this issue with is Facebook

Comment: at least now i know why the chromedriver works differently in headless mode. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what Google chrome does. One way around it would be to use a proxy and modify the headers for you. Or you can use the Firefox driver as that driver does not send different headers when using the headless option.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, using and not using the `--headless` option shouldn't have any major effect on the elements within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) getting rendered but may have a significant difference as far as the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) is concerned.

As an example, when ChromeDriver/Chrome is initialized along with the **`--headless`** option the default *Viewport* is

```
width = 800px, height = 600px
```

Where as when ChromeDriver/Chrome is initialized without the `--headless` option the default *Viewport* is:

```
width = 1050px, height = 708px
```

- Example Code (**Python based**):

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
  size = driver.get_window_size()
  print("Window size: width = {}px, height = {}px".format(size["width"], size["height"]))
  driver.quit()
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  print ("Chrome Initialized")
  size = driver.get_window_size()
  print("Window size: width = {}px, height = {}px".format(size["width"], size["height"]))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Headless Chrome Initialized
  Window size: width = 800px, height = 600px
  Chrome Initialized
  Window size: width = 1050px, height = 708px
  ```

So it can be concluded that with `--headless` option ChromeDriver/Chrome opens the session with reduced *Viewport* and hence the number of elements identified are less.

---

### Solution

While using ChromeDriver/Chrome to initiate a *Browsing Instance* always open in **`maximized`** mode:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```