# Selenium Firefox headless returns different results

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, headless-browser, firefox-headless

When i scrape page that contains products with usage of headless option i get different results.
For the same question one time i get results that are not sorted, and another time with proper sorted order.

Selenium firefox browser:

```
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, executable_path=firefox_driver)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719091/selenium-with-chromedriver-gives-different-results-based-on-headless-on-or-off) post:
"firefox does not send different headers when using the headless option".

How to use headless option to get constant results from scraping?

**Update:**

Its turns out that ads popup window was hiding price sort menu. With setting constant windows size as posted by [DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb), problem was solved.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, using and not using `firefox_options.headless = True` shouldn't have any major effect on the elements within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) getting rendered but may have a significant difference as far as the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) is concerned.

As an example, when GeckoDriver/Firefox is initialized along with the **`--headless`** option the default *Viewport* is **`width = 1366px, height = 768px`** where as when GeckoDriver/Firefox is initialized without the `--headless` option the default *Viewport* is **`width = 1382px, height = 744px`**.

- Example Code:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
  options.headless = True
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  print ("Headless Firefox Initialized")
  size = driver.get_window_size()
  print("Window size: width = {}px, height = {}px".format(size["width"], size["height"]))
  driver.quit()
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  print ("Firefox Initialized")
  size = driver.get_window_size()
  print("Window size: width = {}px, height = {}px".format(size["width"], size["height"]))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Headless Firefox Initialized
  Window size: width = 1366px, height = 768px
  Firefox Initialized
  Window size: width = 1382px, height = 744px
  ```

---

### Conclusion

From the above observation it can be inferred that with `--headless` option GeckoDriver/Firefox opens the *Browsing Context* with reduced *Viewport* and hence the number of elements identified can be **less**.

---

### Solution

While using GeckoDriver/Firefox to initiate a *Browsing Context* always open in **`maximized`** mode or configure through `set_window_size()` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
#options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

---

### tl; dr

You find a couple of relevant discussion on ***window size*** in:

- [python](/questions/tagged/python): [How to set window size in Selenium Chrome Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python/55016352#55016352)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java): [Not able to maximize Chrome Window in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374377/not-able-to-maximize-chrome-window-in-headless-mode/45374670#45374670)

Comment: Hi, i don't asked about maximize or resizing window. The issue is that in headless mode, response context is different then without this mode.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi That can happen due to difference in viewpoint which I have detailed out within the answer.

Comment: Thank You. Its turns out that generated popup ad window was hiding sorting menu. After setup bigger window size problem was solved.