# Start firefox unmaximized with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, awesome-wm

I am using Selenium in Python with Firefox. Firefox is always started in maximized mode, which does not work very well with my tiling window manager Awesome on Linux.

How can I prevent Firefox being opened in maximized mode with Selenium and Python? Or how can I unmaximize a window?

MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

That opens Firefox in maximized mode on my setup. My regular Firefox doesn't open in maximized mode.

I know the function `driver.window_maximize()` which apparently doesn't unmaximize the window.

Comment: You'll want to set the window size. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-do-i-set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set browser width and height in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-do-i-set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Thanks, setting the window size indeed did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an instance of `firefox.options` to add the **argument** `--window-size` to open Firefox in any size as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=900,600")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [How to set window size in Selenium Chrome Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python/55016352#55016352)
- [Selenium Firefox headless returns different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031706/selenium-firefox-headless-returns-different-results/59033268#59033268)

Comment: Thanks, setting the window size did the trick. I had to use commandline options `-width=900` and `-height=600`, though. Also, I got the warning that `firefox_options=options` is deprecated and should be replaced by `options`.

Comment: @soelderer That was my bad, replaced `firefox_options` with `options`. Let me know the status.

Comment: Works just fine, thanks. However, the right commandline options (at least for my version of firefox on linux) appear to be `-width=` and `height=`, `--window-size` didn't work for me.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure about the specific version of firefox on linux you are using, but it's possible. Thanks for the update, which version/flavour (linux) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 71.0 on Arch.