# How to zoom in a webpage using Python Selenium in FireFox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, zooming

I am working on Ubuntu and writing a web automation script which can open a page and zoom in the page. I am using `python` `selenium`. Below is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/")

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
```

This opens the browser and opens the wikipedia page. Now I have to do the zoom in functionality. For this I tried below line of code:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='150%'")
```

It didn't work. So I tried below line of code:

```
driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(1.50)";')

driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransformOrigin = "0 0";')
```

It kind of worked but the webpage height and width were disturbed and it looks like below:

[image]

It should look like below:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest some good working solution to zoom in a webpage using `python selenium` in `FireFox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find any working solution so what I did is, I used `pyautogui` to simulate the keys.

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.press('+')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
```

This made the webpage zoom to `110%`. You can run it again to make it to `120%` and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code is breaking the Xpath access:   `driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='150%'")`

I observed error when I am using pyautogui with 'headless'.
`options.add_argument("--headless=new")`

**Solution:** when using

> options.add_argument("--headless=new")

```
   options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
   browser.set_window_size(1080, 740)
   options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

**Solution link:**

[Selenium Firefox headless returns different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031706/selenium-firefox-headless-returns-different-results/59033268#59033268)